# Specifying which category to treat as the base with 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, categorical-data

In understand that when I have a category variable in a model passed to a `statsmodels` `fit` that dummy variables will automatically be generated for the categories. For example if I have a variable 'Location' with values 'IndianOcean', 'Thailand', 'China' and 'Mars' I will get variables in my model of the form

```
Location[T.Thailand]
```

with one of the value not represented. By default the excluded variable seems to be the least common one. Is there a way to specify — ideally within the model specification — which value is treated as the "base value" and excluded?

Comment: It seems that using `C` in the formula (as in `... + C(Location, Treatment) + ...` does the trick, but this results in some pretty [ugly category names that I'd like to avoid](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/90190/16694).

Comment: I don't understand this. Do you write e.g. C(Location, 'IndianOcean') if you want 'IndianOcean' to be the reference category from the variable 'Location'?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can pass a `reference` arg to the Treatment contrast, using syntax like

`"y ~ C(Location, Treatment(reference='China'))"`

http://patsy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.Treatment

If you have a better suggestion for naming conventions please file an issue with patsy.

Comment: To be explicit, the syntax is `"y ~ C(Location, Treatment(reference='China'))" `.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal thanks for clarifying. I wish the original answer actually included code.

Comment: `"y ~ C(Location, Treatment('China'))"` works as well.

Comment: @jseabold ,  I'm getting error as follows PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable. while doing the above two methods. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: I am having this problem as well. "TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable"

Answer (score 4):

If you use single quotes to wrap your string, reference's argument needs to be wrapped with double quotes. Very easy mistake to make. I was using single quotes on both.

For example:

```
'y ~ C(Location, Treatment(reference="China"))'
```

is correct.

```
'y ~ C(Location, Treatment(reference='China'))'
```

is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, maybe someone will find this one helpfull. I needed to set a new baseline category for the dependent variable, I had no idea how to do it. I searched and found nothing, so i simply added a "_" for the other categories. If you have 3 categories A, B, C, and you want your baseline to be C you just change the labeles from A and B to _A and _B. It works. I appears that the baseline category is defined by sorted()

Maybe someone knows a proper way to do it, this is not very phytonic, ja.